# How to Set Delivery date based on various conditions in Shopify Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to make a small feature on my store front which shows customer a date they can expect their order to be delivered. I have done the basic estimate but now I am trying to build conditions into it, such as warehouse cut off time.
For the past 2 days I now been able to crack it and now seek some advice.

My current code is not calculating is days as it should and I'm not sure why.

**The conditions:**

- Warehouse cut off time = 1pm
- Warehouse dispatch is Mon-Fri (Friday 1pm Cut off)
- Delivery is Mon-Sat (No delivery on Sundays)

**My code so far**

`current_time` is set to a test date but will be based on current time once complete*

```
{% assign current_time = "2023-04-14 13:30:00" | date: "%s" %}

{% assign cutoff_time = current_time | date: "%Y-%m-%d" | append: " 13:00:00" | date: "%s" %}

{% assign day_of_week = current_time | date: "%u" %}

{% assign delivery_date = current_time | plus: 172800 %}

{% if current_time > cutoff_time and day_of_week != "6" or day_of_week != "7" %}
    {% assign delivery_date = delivery_date | plus: 86400 %}
    {% assign day_of_week = day_of_week | plus: "1" %}
{% endif %}

{{ day_of_week }}

{% if day_of_week == "6" %}
  {% assign delivery_date = delivery_date | plus: 172800 %}
day 6 triggered
{% elsif day_of_week == "7" %}
  {% assign delivery_date = delivery_date | plus: 86400 %}
day 7 triggered
{% endif %}

{% assign delivery_date_day = delivery_date | date: "%u" %}

{% if delivery_date_day == "7" %}
  {% assign delivery_date = delivery_date | plus: 86400 %}
{% endif %}

{% assign delivery_date_formatted = delivery_date | date: "%A, %B %d" %}

<div>
  <span style="margin-right:10px; float:left;" fill="none">{% include 'del-box' %}</span>
  <span style="margin:0px; overflow:hidden; display:block;">Delivered by <b>{{ delivery_date_formatted }}</b></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to use Javascript for this, liquid code not output current till due cache issue correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix!

The reason it didn't work is because `{% assign day_of_week = day_of_week | plus: "1" %}` was turning a string into an integer, so all I had to do was turn it back into a string so the rest of the code could pick it up

Line added was `{% assign day_of_week = day_of_week | append: "" %}`